# Regex, anonymise all matches, per line where there is 1 mandatory match with various optional matches

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've research this quite heavily now but nothing seems to be getting me close

Below is an excerpt of a csv file.  I need to anonymise certain lines where there is a match found for an email address.  Once a match is found I need to also anonymise other certain fields that might also be present on the same line.

I read about ? making preceding token's optional so though it would be relatively easy to specific an optional group and a mandatory group but I can't it to work.

This is the example data:

```
test1,rod.p@nono.com,bbb,123456789,987654321,aaa,121
test2,aaa,rod.p@yes.com,123456789,aaa,bbb,987654321,122,rod.p@yes.com,aaa,123456
test3,rod.p@yesyes.com,123456789,987654321,aaa,123
```

Based on the below syntax, I need the line test2 being matched only and specifically the parts

```
aaa [optional as long as the email address has been matched on the same line]
bbb [optional as long as the email address has been matched on the same line]
rod.p@yes.com [mandatory]
```

(please note the email address may appear more than once)

The below syntax will highlight the right parts but will also select the aaa and bbb on the other rows that don't have the correct email address.

```
(aaa|bbb)?(rod\.p@yes\.com)?
```

so I realised that I need to define a start and end like ^ and $ but this is when I'm getting stuck and anything I do doesn't make it work.

```
^(aaa|bbb)?.*(rod\.p@yes\.com).*$
```

This matches the whole line of test2 (I guess this is because of the '.*') but I need to only match the individual parts so that I can replace them with the word anonymised.  I've tried various things but haven't managed to work it working yet.  Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

PS testing this using regexr.com/ with multiline and global flags enabled.

Comment: Here is a _pattern_ to match the email address, `(?<=,)[^,]+@[^,]+(?=,|$)`.  For clarification, you're saying that _"aaa"_ or _"bbb"_, must be matched, only when the email address has appeared more than once?

Comment: Hi @Reilas, nearly... only when the email address has appeared one or more times must the optional words be looked for and matched on the same line.  The email address will be static ie. I don't need to search for any email address, just a specific one, ie. rod.p@yes.com.

Comment: Try, `(?<=(?:aaa|bbb),)?(rod\.p@yes\.com)(?=,(?:aaa|bbb))?` to _match_, or `(?:(aaa|bbb),)?(rod\.p@yes\.com)(?:,(aaa|bbb))?` to _capture_.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax's - did these work for you?  I'm getting an error (invalid quantifier) for the _match_ and the _capture_ doesn't pick up all the aaa or bbb bits for the Test 2 line.  I'm using Regexr.com to test.

Comment: Update..... I've just tried it on regex101.com and it works better but for the _match_ it only finds the email addresses and for the _capture_ it only picks up the aaa before the first email address or the aaa after the second email address.  It's not picking up the aaa (let alone the bbb) in the middle.

Comment: I believe I understand, now.  You are looking to capture any _"aaa"_, or _"bbb"_, within the line, when the email address is present.  You should be using a coding language for this, it would be much simpler.

Comment: Yes that's right re the capturing.  I was hoping to use this regex syntax in notepad++ after it had done a file search, searching for the email address.  One thought, the notepad++ search facility does in fact find the specific line that the email address is on but I'm not sure how I would limit any regex to work just on that specific line.  That's why I was trying to search for the email in regex too.  Do you have any suggestions or apps that might be better suited?  Thanks.

Comment: If it's just a _capture_, and not a _find-and-replace_, utilize one of those websites, regex101 works quite well.  First, isolate the lines with, `.*rod\.p@yes\.com.*`, switch to the _"List"_ function, on the left-side menu, and use a `$0\n` _match specifier_, to print each _match_.  Copy these values into a new regex101 tab, and use a new _pattern_, `(aaa|bbb)`, with the same `$0\n` specifier, to get the results.  Otherwise, try _Python_, or even _JavaScript_.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll take that approach

Comment: You will need to check first if the e-mail occurs in the line by use of a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and if so, match the e-mail and the desired parts. It can be done by [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) (continue) and [`\K`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) (reset match start). Search for [`(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*?(?:,|^)(rod\.p@yes\.com)(?=,|$))).*?(?:,|^)\K(?:(?1)|aaa|bbb)(?=,|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/gjq9XK/1) and replace with `anonymised` (*uncheck* dot matches newline, click "replace all").

Comment: @bobblebubble, that's works! fantastic!  thank you so much plus also for the explanation.  Not sure how I highlight or flag your reply as the answer so have just upvoted it. :)

Comment: @Rodp Glad that helped! I put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`\G` (chain matches)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [`\K` (reset match start)](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) based regex. Search for

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*?(?:,|^)(rod\.p@yes\.com)(?=,|$))).*?(?:,|^)\K(?:(?1)|aaa|bbb)(?=,|$)
```

and replace with `anonymised` - [See this demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gjq9XK/1).

In Notepad++

- uncheck *dot matches newline*
- click the "replace all" button

---

In short the pattern is meant to identify lines containing the specified e-mail by use of a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in the first part. The second part matches in the identfied lines either the e-mail wich gets matched by [`(?1)` a reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to the *first* [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) subpattern [`|` or](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) any of the specified substrings `aaa`, `bbb`.

The key part `(?:\G(?!^)|subpattern)` chains matches to `subpattern` (in your case all beginnings of lines if an e-mail occurs anywhere later in the line). The *lookahead* `(?!^)` just prevents `\G` from matching at start (default behaviour). In between e-mail, `aaa` and `bbb`, the `.*?` matches [any characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) [lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/5527985). `\K` is used to reset the *match start* as we don't want the `.*?` and comma parts.